# drop down selection based on other drop down selection and date format

Tags: date, format, powerapps

I have this excel sheet with several events in the "Gremium" column and with the event date in the "Gremientermin" column.
[image]

Then I have this powerapp:

[image]

The 2nd dropdown is dependent on the first dropdown and only selects the date specific to the event names ("Gremium").
The code for dropdown2 is:

```
AddColumns(
Filter(
Tabelle1;
Gremium = Dropdown2_1.Selected.Kürzel
);
"EDate";
Text(
Gremientermin;
"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

but the formatting does not work and because of that the i think the filter on the gallery does not work:
[image]

The code for the filter in the gallery in the **Item** property is:

```
Filter(Tabelle1; Gremium = Dropdown2_1.Selected.Kürzel; Gremientermin = Dropdown2_2.Selected.Gremientermin; StartsWith(Aktivität;Suche.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can try changing the code for dropdown2 to use the Text function with a custom format string that matches the date format in your Excel sheet. For example, if your Excel sheet has dates in the format "dd.mm.yyyy", you can use the following code for dropdown2:

```
AddColumns(
Filter(
Tabelle1;
Gremium = Dropdown2_1.Selected.Kürzel
);
"EDate";
Text(
Gremientermin;
"dd.mm.yyyy"))
```

Note that you should replace "dd.mm.yyyy" with the actual date format in your Excel sheet.
Once you have fixed the formatting issue, you should be able to filter the gallery based on the selected values in both dropdowns using the code you provided:

```
Filter(Tabelle1; Gremium = Dropdown2_1.Selected.Kürzel; Gremientermin = Dropdown2_2.Selected.EDate; StartsWith(Aktivität;Suche.Text))
```

Again, note that you should replace "EDate" with the actual name of the column you added in dropdown2 using the AddColumns function.

Comment: I changed the code for dropdown2 as you said. The I changed the (part of) code in the Items property of the gallery to Gremientermin = DateValue(Dropdown2_2.Selected.EDate;"dd.mm.yyyy") now the error: 'the language code "null" is not supported'